# Create load plans in oracle data integrator with groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy, scripting, oracle-data-integrator

I would like to create load plans in ODI (oracle data integrator) with groovy. I am using a groovy script for a migration.

The groovy documentation for ODI does not cover any of that (i didn't find anything). Maybe someone here has already done it?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the package related to Load Plan in the SDK documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/oracle/odi/domain/runtime/loadplan/package-summary.html

The root entity is the class [OdiLoadPlan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/index.html)